# How to use switch case for validate multiple variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am using one javascript where i used if condition to validate more than two variable, Based on that i am setting the data.
Below is javascript code:

```js
if (twitterPicLink != "" || twitterMediaLink != "" || twitteHeartServeLink != "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet'>";
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-image'><img src='" + imgSrc + "' title='Tweet icon'></div>";
}
if (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink != "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + " " + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;<br/>" + twitterPicLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
else if (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink != "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;<br/>" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
else if (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink == "" && twitteHeartServeLink != "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitteHeartServeLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
else if (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink == "" && twitteHeartServeLink != "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterPicLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
else if (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink != "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
else if (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink == "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitterPicLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
else if (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink == "" && twitteHeartServeLink == "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitterPicLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
else if (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink == "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
}
```

How can i change above code to switch case validation?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help

```
switch (twitterPicLink) {
  case "":
    switch (twitterMediaLink) {
        case "":
            switch (twitteHeartServeLink) {
                case "":

                [break;]
                default:                    
                    htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitteHeartServeLink + "</p></div></div>";
                [break;]
            }
        [break;]
        default:
            switch (twitteHeartServeLink) {
                case "":
                    htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
                [break;]
                default:
                    htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;<br/>" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
                [break;]
            }

        [break;]
    }
    [break;]

  default:    
    switch (twitterMediaLink) {
        case "":
            switch (twitteHeartServeLink) {
                case "":
                    htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitterPicLink + "</p></div></div>";
                [break;]
                default:
                    htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterPicLink + "</p></div></div>";
                [break;]
            }
        [break;]
        default:
            switch (twitteHeartServeLink) {
                case "":
                    htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitterPicLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
                [break;]
                default:
                    htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + " " + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;<br/>" + twitterPicLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
                [break;]
            }
        [break;]
    }
    [break;]
}
```

Comment: While this technically answers the question the resulting code would be really aweful. I'd consider nested `switch` statements amongst the ugliest code one could write...

Answer (score 0):

Think about your design. Even though this does not technically answer the question you could to the following with a factory-ish class

```
if (twitterPicLink != "" || twitterMediaLink != "" || twitteHeartServeLink != "") {
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet'>";
      htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-image'><img src='" + imgSrc + "' title='Tweet icon'></div>";
}
htmlDiv += tweetBodyFactory.create(twitterPicLink, twitterMediaLink, twitterHeartSaveLink);
```

Within your factory you can use composition to hold factory implementations, that define the fields `PicLinkIsDefined`, `MediaLinkIsDefined` and `HeartSaveLinkIsDefined`. With

```
var matchingFactory = factories.find(f => (f.PicLinkIsDefined && twitterPicLink != "" || !f.PicLinkIsDefined && tweitterPicLink == "")
    && (f.MediaLinkIsDefined && twitterMediaLink != "" || !f.MediaLinkIsDefined && twitterMediaLink == "")
    && (f.HeartSaveLinkIsDefined && twitterHeartSaveLink != "" || !f.HeartSaveLinkIsDefined && twitterHeartSaveLink == ""));
if(matchingFactory != undefined)
{
    return matchingFactory.create(twitterPicLink, twitterMediaLink, twitterHeartSaveLink);
}
// error handling here
```

you can select the matching factory and build the HTML. It'll be a bit more code (with all the factory implementations), but in the end it'll be much cleaner.

*I know* that it's a bit loose interpretation of the factory pattern, but still a good way to structure the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**Try  cover your code in switch case..**

Please check it once..

```
switch (true) {
        case (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink != ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + " " + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;<br/>" + twitterPicLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
        case (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink != ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;<br/>" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
        case (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink == "" && twitteHeartServeLink != ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitteHeartServeLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
        case (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink == "" && twitteHeartServeLink != ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterPicLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
        case (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink != ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitteHeartServeLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
        case (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink == ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "<br/>" + twitterPicLink + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
        case (twitterPicLink != "" && twitterMediaLink == "" && twitteHeartServeLink == ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitterPicLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
        case (twitterPicLink == "" && twitterMediaLink != "" && twitteHeartServeLink == ""):
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-body'><p>" + twittedText + "&nbsp;" + twitterMediaLink + "</p></div></div>";
            break;
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet'>";
            htmlDiv += "<div class='tweet-image'><img src='" + imgSrc + "' title='Tweet icon'></div>";

        default:

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can study [switch - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) from MDN

Here's a code synxtax on how it is used.

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
  case value2:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches valueN
    [break;]
  default:
    //Statements executed when none of the values match the value of the expression
    [break;]
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. The OP asked how he can transform this specific if-else to a switch block

Comment: i prefer that they learn it to understand deeply how it works, and not spoon feed OPs.

Comment: Alright, that's a fine goal - admittedly - but still makes no sense in the context of the question, since the conditions depend on multiple variables and a `switch`referes to a single variale.